# UIPickerview controller not able to pick image and use in xcode4.2 but works well on xcode 3.2

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, xcode4.2, xcode3.2

i have a UIImagePickerController this code below runs fine on XCODE 3.2 but app hangs wen complied from XCODE 4.2

Also but sometimes it runs on some other machines once .

Can anyone tell me d reason from this?
Thanks alot.

```
    -(IBAction)showActionSheet:(id)sender {
    UIActionSheet *popupQuery = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add Photo" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Take Photo" otherButtonTitles:@"Choose From Library", nil];
    popupQuery.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;
    [popupQuery showInView:self.view];
    [popupQuery release];
}

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {

        [self addLoaderWithtext:@"Please wait..."];
        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
//        [self.mtextView resignFirstResponder];
//        [self.mtextView2 resignFirstResponder];
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
        [picker release];



    } else if (buttonIndex == 1) {

        [self addLoaderWithtext:@"Please wait..."];
        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
        [picker release];

    } 



}



- (IBAction)pushUpload {


    [self removeLoader];
    [self addLoaderWithtext:@"Uploading Image..."];


    double compressionRatio=0;

    UIImage *inputImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[imageView.image CGImage] scale:1.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationRight];
    //imageView.image = [[UIImage imageView.image]_imageScaledToSize:CGSizeMake(32.0f, 32.0f) interpolationQuality:1];
    NSData *imageData=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(inputImage,compressionRatio);
    NSString *urlString = @"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    //while ([imageData length]>1) { 
//        compressionRatio=compressionRatio*0.5;
//        imageData=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image,compressionRatio);
//  }
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\".jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    imageurl = returnString;
    NSLog(@"returnString:%@",returnString);

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4.0 target:self selector:@selector(onTick1:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];



}
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {


[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0 target:self selector:@selector(onTick1:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
double compressionRatio=1;
imageView.image=UIImageJPEGRepresentation([info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"],compressionRatio);
while ([imageView.image length]>1) { 
    compressionRatio=compressionRatio*0.1;
    imageView.image=UIImageJPEGRepresentation([info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"],compressionRatio);


}




imageView.image = image;

[self   pushUpload];
[picker.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
  [picker.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
  }

Comment: the source code looks fine for me, what is inside the addLoaderWithText

Comment: its my custom loader doesnt make a diffrnce if i comment it